# SQL Query to find rows containing "%"

Tags: sql

I know we can use the LIKE predicate in an SQL query to find rows with alpha-numeric and special characters (WHERE desc LIKE '%#%'). But how do I find rows containing the "%" symbol? (WHERE desc LIKE '%%%' returns *all* rows).

Comment: What [tag:rdbms] are you using?

Comment: Did you research this?  Seems like a pretty easy answer to find with a quick Google search.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on your DB engine.
`\%` is the escape character for `%` in MySQL and Oracle.

```
WHERE desc LIKE '%\%%'
```

Comment: juergen d, thanks for the quick response, but that didn't work for me (I am using SQL Server 2012).  However, this worked: WHERE desc LIKE '%[%]%' (see [link] http://www.techtamasha.com/escape-single-quotes-and-wild-cards-_-in-ms-sql/20)

Answer (score 1):

Escape characters are tricky to follow in SQL Server. Just make it a literal

```
WHERE desc LIKE '%[%]%'
```

As per the section ["Using Wildcard Characters As Literals"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx)

> To use a wildcard character as a literal character, enclose the wildcard character in brackets.

Answer (score 0):

ANSI SQL lets you specify escape character using an `escape` clause, e.g.

```
where desc like '%\%%' escape '\'
```